# What is an alloy called when it melts at the same temperature as something else?

Tags: terminology

What is an alloy called when it melts at the same temperature as something else? For example, if there is an alloy that melts at the same temperature as glass then it will be susceptible to enameling and it is called an XXX-alloy.

As I recall, the term begins with the letters "eu-".

Comment: I don't think there is a term for that. Besides, glass does not really have a well-defined melting temperature. Then again, there is a word "[eutectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eutectic_system)", but its meaning is quite different.

Comment: Do you mean melting at the same point as something else on the same (binary) phase diagram? Otherwise, many alloys can be made to melt at a wide range of temperatures (simple example: lead-tin solders come (came) in many different compositions with different melting points).

Answer (score 5):

> Isotectic substances are those which melt at the same temperature.

Ref.: Heycock, C. T.; Neville, F. H. "On the freezing points of triple alloys of gold, cadmium, and tin". J. Chem. Soc., Trans., 1891, 59, 936-966

But be aware that this term is very rarely used.